# HTTPD pretty URL for NextCloud

Tags: apache-http-server, redirection, url, nextcloud

I've just installed Nextcloud server on my CentOS 7 distro. What I would like to have is a redirection from the "cloud.mycompany.com" to "cloud.mycompany.com/nextcloud". Also if you can tell me how to make pretty URL with apache, so the users won't see complete URLs, only basics, or at least exclude the nextcloud tag from the URL.

Here is my current conf file:

```
Alias /nextcloud "/var/www/html/com.mycompany.cloud/"

<Directory /var/www/html/com.mycompany.cloud/>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  AllowOverride All

 <IfModule mod_dav.c>
  Dav off
 </IfModule>

 SetEnv HOME /var/www/html/com.mycompany.cloud
 SetEnv HTTP_HOME /var/www/html/com.mycompany.cloud

</Directory>
```

As you can tell, from my question: I'm completely new to Apache2, so sorry if the question is too easy.

Answer (score 0):

> What I would like to have is a redirection from the "cloud.mycompany.com" to "cloud.mycompany.com/nextcloud".

This is likely a bad idea since it is extremely easy to set up an infinite redirect loop. You should simply put your NextCloud 
folder (what you have under Alias now) as the default directory for an Apache virtual host (cloud.mycompany.com).

> Also if you can tell me how to make pretty URL with apache, so the users won't see complete URLs, only basics, or at least exclude the nextcloud tag from the URL.

If you set up a virtual host as described, you shouldn't need to hide /nextcloud in the URL. Regarding making "pretty" URLs, you may want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20563772/3395469) to see what is and isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

As @Anaksunaman pointed out, removing `nextcloud` from the URL can be achieved by using a VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName com.mycompany.cloud
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/com.mycompany.cloud/
    <Directory /var/www/html/com.mycompany.cloud/>
        Options +FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride All
        <IfModule mod_dav.c>
            Dav off
        </IfModule>
        SetEnv HOME /var/www/html/com.mycompany.cloud
        SetEnv HTTP_HOME /var/www/html/com.mycompany.cloud
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Nextcloud has built-in support to remove the `index.php` string from the URL. This can be done by adding `'htaccess.RewriteBase' => '/',` to the Nextcloud`config/config.php` file. Next run `php occ maintenance:update:htaccess` inside the Nextcloud directory. This commnand must be executed using the Apache webserver. On Debian/Ubuntu use `sudo -u www-data php occ..` and on Centos `sudo -u apache php occ...`